# Unable to build ANTLR4 on Ubuntu due to `package is not visible` errors

Tags: java, linux, maven, compiler-errors, antlr4

I'm trying to build [ANTLR4](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4) on Ubuntu using maven:

```
mvn install -DskipTests
```

but it throws the following errors:

```
CommentHasStringValueProcessor.java:[9,27] package com.sun.tools.javac.main is not visible
  (package com.sun.tools.javac.main is declared in module jdk.compiler, which does not export it to the unnamed module)
CommentHasStringValueProcessor.java:[11,27] package com.sun.tools.javac.tree is not visible
...
```

I tried using different workarounds from StackOverflow but it didn't help. Could somebody elaborate on what exactly should I fix?

For some reason, it works on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

`ANTLR4`, Ubuntu 20.04 build example.

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless maven

cd /home/name/tmp/
git clone https://github.com/antlr/antlr4.git
cd antlr4/
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1G"
mvn clean
mvn -DskipTests install
.
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] -----------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:21 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-12-02T23:31:50+01:00
[INFO] -----------------------------------------
```

Ref. https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/building-antlr.md